# How to Use Required Field validator on a check box CHECKED true or false

Tags: asp.net

I  have a user setting form on which there is a dropdownlist to change some kind of user setting, on the other hand I have a check box to change a password also or not on the same page. When check box is check

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbPassword" runat="server" CssClass="checkbox" onclick="showhidepasswordFields()" />

<div class="col-xs-9 form-inline" id="PChange" style="display: none;">
   <asp:TextBox ID="tbxOldPass" runat="server" TextMode="Password" CssClass="form-control" Width="122px"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Enter Old Password"  ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="tbxOldPass" ValidationGroup="grp"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
   <asp:TextBox ID="tbxNewPass" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Width="122px" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="tbxNewPassRFV" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbxNewPass" ErrorMessage="Enter New Passwod" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="grp"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
   <asp:TextBox ID="tbxConfirmPass" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Width="122px" CssClass="form-control" ></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="tbxConfirmPass" ErrorMessage="Reconfirm Password" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="grp" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
   <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Paswords are not Same" ForeColor="Red" ControlToCompare="tbxNewPass" ControlToValidate="tbxConfirmPass" ValidationGroup="grp"></asp:CompareValidator>
</div>
```

gets visible where user have to enter old and new password. I want that when check box is checked then required field validator works other wise not.

```
<asp:Button ID="tbnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" OnClick="tbnUpdate_Click" CssClass="btn btn-success" CausesValidation="false" ValidationGroup="grp" />
```

If I set `CausesValidation="false"` then validation is not done. If i set it true then if checkbox is not checked validator triggers. Is there there any way that valdation only done when check box is checked other wise just update the setting from drop down list?

Java script function to show/hide div.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function showhidepasswordFields() {
            if (document.getElementById('<%=cbPassword.ClientID%>').checked) {
                document.getElementById('PChange').style.display = 'block';
            }
            else if (!document.getElementById('<%=cbPassword.ClientID%>').checked) {
                document.getElementById('PChange').style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Please show all relevant code. I don't see any checkbox in the code you've shared. I expect you'll need to write a custom validator for something like this, however.

Comment: I have added the code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `CustomValidator` for that. The first function just test wether the CheckBox is checked or not. The other one adds more logic like checking if a TextBox also has a value. Just change the `ClientValidationFunction` for testing.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="CustomValidator" ClientValidationFunction="testCheckBoxAndTextBox"></asp:CustomValidator>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function testCheckBox(sender, element) {
        element.IsValid = $("#<%= CheckBox1.ClientID %>").prop('checked');
    }

    function testCheckBoxAndTextBox(sender, element) {
        var isValid = false;
        if ($("#<%= CheckBox1.ClientID %>").prop('checked') == true && $("#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>").val() != "") {
            isValid = true;
        }
        element.IsValid = isValid;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

.aspx:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbTest" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="cbTest_CheckedChanged"></asp:CheckBox> 
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTest" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqFV" Enabled="false" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*****" ControlToValidate="txtTest" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

.aspx.cs:

```
protected void cbTest_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    reqFV.Enabled = cbTest.Checked;
}
```